# Python csv from database query adding a custom column to csv file

Tags: python, sql, csv

here is what I try to achieve my current code is working fine I get the query to run on my sql server but I will need to gather information from several servers. How would I add a column with the dbserver listed in that column?

```
import pyodbc
import csv

f = open("dblist.ini")
dbserver,UID,PWD = [ variable[variable.find("=")+1 :] for variable in f.readline().split("~")]

connectstring = "DRIVER={SQL server};SERVER=" + dbserver + ";DATABASE=master;UID="+UID+";PWD="+PWD

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectstring)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

fd = open('mssql1.txt', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

cursor.execute(sqlFile)


with open("out.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = '!')
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description]) # write headers
    csv_writer.writerows(cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the extra information in your sql query. For example:

```
select "dbServerName", * from table;
```

Your cursor will return with an extra column in front of your real data that has the db Server name. The downside to this method is you're transferring a little more extra data.